# Confusion matrix doesn't display properly

Tags: python, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix, ipython

I am trying to plot a `confusion matrix` using the `Logistic Regression` for a `multi-class` dataset.

But the problem is when I plot the `confusion matrix` it only plot a `confusion matrix` for binary classification.

Here is where I am plotting it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv("WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv")
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

LRModel = LogisticRegression(C=100, max_iter=5500)

LRModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
predicted_values_ = LRModel.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_values_)

misclassified = (y_test != predicted_values_).sum()
misclassified
```

```
import seaborn as sn

# plt.figure()
sn.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Actual")
```

And I get this matrix as shown below.

[image]

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

**This is where I am using Logistic Regression for multi-class scenario**

Comment: Did you check the number of classes in y_test?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check how many classes y_test has.

if Y is array-

```
np.unique(y_test)
```

If y is DataFrame column,

```
y_test.unique()
```

Looks like y_test has only 2 classes.

As far as I know HR-Employee-Attrition.csv dataset has only 2 classes.